# What is the syntax to require a template variable to be void?

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

Is there a way to write a `requires requires` expression to apprehend that a template parameter is void?

I believe it is legal to make the value of `std::is_void_v<ParmThree>` a parameter of the template. However, I cannot formulate a syntax to check this in a requirement - for being either true or false.

Is it possible? How would it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`requires requires` works because the nested (second) `requires` returns a bool.

Since you already have a bool, you can just do `requires std::is_void_v<T>`:

```
template <typename T>
requires std::is_void_v<T>
struct A {};
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.