# How check that function is non-void function?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have this code:

```
template<class T>
concept Indexable = requires(T t, size_t val){
    !std::is_same<decltype(t.operator[](val)), void>::value;
};
```

it doesn't work on this test and I don't understand how check that function is non-void.

```
struct bad {
    void operator[](size_t) {
       // need to return 
    }
};
static_assert(!Indexable<bad>, "fail");
```

But in other cases like this it works:

```
static_assert(Indexable<std::map<int, std::string>>, "fail");
```

I have tried void, void() and other templates, but it did end by success.

Comment: Please don't use traits like `is_same` in concepts when there is an equivalent `same_as` concept.

Comment: Try using `std::is_void`? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_void, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71568155/what-is-the-syntax-to-require-a-template-variable-to-be-void

Comment: Note that your concept is checking whether the given line *compiles*, not whether the line is *true*. As people have pointed out there are better ways to write this concept, but you can introduce a [nested requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/requires)

Answer (score 4):

Requires expressions already have syntax for "check to see if the result of some expression satisfies a concept." So you should employ that.

```
template<typename T>
concept is_void_type = std::is_void_v<T>;

template<typename T>
concept is_not_void_type = !is_void_type<T>;

template<typename T>
concept indexable = requires(T t, std::size_t sz)
{
  {t[sz]} -> is_not_void_type;
};
```

[Here's a working example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4nxhbf89e).